# How to properly set the 100% DIV height to match document/window height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I have a wrapper positioned to center with an y-repeated background image:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        ...some content
    </div>
</body>

#wrapper{
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
background-image: url(image.jpg) 250px 0px repeat-y;
}
```

Problem: when the window size is higher than the wrapper's height inherited from its content, the image obviously doesn't repeat on y-axis all the way to the bottom of the window.

I've used jQuery to dynamically apply inline CSS style to the wrapper according to actual document height (when DOM is ready and on window resize event):

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#wrapper').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
    });
});
```

The problem with this approach is that every time one extends the window height to a size larger than the previously resized largest size, the document height extends by this difference, essentially making the wrapper DIV infinite if you keep resizing the window infinitely and have a infinite vertical display space.

On a typical 30" inch display with 1600px height, when user opens the website with a window height 1000px and wrapper is 800px high, the jQuery above sets the height to 1000px tiling the background image correctly. At this point, once the user extends the window size to e.g 1400px, the 1400px is a new document size "remembered default" and doesn't update itself even if the user resizes his window back to the original 1000px height, adding **400px to the scrollbar height** at the bottom.

How to fix this?

UPDATE: (window).height doesn't seem to work, because window height is a viewport height. When your viewport is smaller than the content and you scroll it, the wrapper always stays the size of the viewport and doesn't extend to the bottom of the current viewport position.

Comment: Put the back ground image in a separate class.  Then remove and re-add that class after resize or during resize?

Comment: Try doing `$(window).height()` instead of `$(document).height()`

Comment: $(window).height() is not correct, e.g. if your window size is just 200px high, the DIV then stays 200px high as well. When you scroll, the repeat-y background stops on the 200px treshold while the actual content is much longer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out myself with the help of someone's answer. But he deleted it for some reason.

Here's the solution:

1. remove all CSS height hacks and 100% heights
2. Use 2 nested wrappers, one in another, e.g. #wrapper and #truecontent
3. Get the height of a browser viewport. IF it's larger than #wrapper, then set inline CSS for #wrapper to match the current browser viewport height (while keeping #truecontent intact)
4. Listen on (window).resize event and ONLY apply inline CSS height IF the viewport is larger than the height of #truecontent, otherwise keep intact

   ```
   $(function(){
       var windowH = $(window).height();
       var wrapperH = $('#wrapper').height();
       if(windowH > wrapperH) {                            
           $('#wrapper').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
       }                                                                               
       $(window).resize(function(){
           var windowH = $(window).height();
           var wrapperH = $('#wrapper').height();
           var differenceH = windowH - wrapperH;
           var newH = wrapperH + differenceH;
           var truecontentH = $('#truecontent').height();
           if(windowH > truecontentH) {
               $('#wrapper').css('height', (newH)+'px');
           }

       })          
   });
   ```

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way is to add the:

```
$('#ID').css("height", $(document).height());
```

after the correct page height is determined by the browser. If the document height is changed once more re-run the above code.

Comment: Perfect. Outside Flexbox this is the neatest approach. You could argue that requiring javascript is a weakness, but as this trick is usually purely cosmetic I see no issue.

Comment: Simple and easy. Thank you.

Comment: yea, this should be the valid choice

Answer (score 11):

You could make it `absolute` and put zeros to `top` and `bottom` that is:

```css
#fullHeightDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops, this would make it 100% width AND 100% height. Omit `left` and `right` CSS attribute :)

Comment: I need the wrapper to be centered and inherit its background-image relative position to wrapper position.

Comment: This is an awesome solution to the problem posted.  Good idea!

Comment: It doesn't work - it only extends if you're extending the window height. But if you shrink the window and scroll the content, it doesn't tile correctly.

Comment: @JoshJones no, it's not. If the #fullHeightDiv has a parent with position relative and height or width 1px, you are F . U . C .. not ok

Comment: does not work if element is nested inside other styled elements that are not absolute

Answer (score 6):

simplest way i found is viewport-height in css..

```
div {height: 100vh;}
```

this takes the viewport-height of the browser-window and updates it during resizes.

see ["can i use" for browser compatibility list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Answer (score 4):

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work -- when you start with a small window size and scroll, the DIV height is not extending and stays 100% of the original window size.

Comment: I have fixed it be adding `#wrapper { min-height:100%; }`  When I tested it it worked.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you again and i'll tweak it.

Comment: I tested it in chrome, IE 8, and Lunascape running trident and gecko engines and it worked for me in each of them.  Unless there is some quirk to it that i'm missing.

Comment: height: 100% and min-height: 100% makes the DIV 100% height of the viewport. This is incorrect. Viewport can be smaller than the actual document size.

Answer (score 2):

this is how i answered that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizebg(){
        $('#background').css("height", $(document).height());
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizebg(); 
    });
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        resizebg(); 
    });
    //initial call
    resizebg();

</script>
```

css:

```
#background{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

so basically on every resizing event i will overwrite the height of the div in this case an image that i use as overlay for the background and have it with opacity not so colorful also i can tint it in my case with the background color.

but thats another story

Answer (score 1):

Use `#element{ height:100vh}`

This will set the height of the `#element` to 100% of `viewport`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`.

Comment: Doesn't work -- when you start with a small window size and scroll, the DIV height is not extending and stays 100% of the original window size.

Comment: In a complex page with many elements with styles set on them, if the element you want to set the height on is nested inside other elements, this will not work properly, or at all (the exact situations under which this fails vary by browser too).

Answer (score 0):

hows this

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
background: url('image.JPG') 250px 0px repeat-y;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function handleResize() {
var h = $(window).height();
        $('#wrapper').css({'height':h+'px'});
}
$(function(){
        handleResize();

        $(window).resize(function(){
        handleResize();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                ...some content
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly when you resize the window to a small height and then scroll the content.